# Help reading a 125khz FSK RFID

Tags: serial, timers, rfid

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/3y5bg3/help_reading_a_lf_fsk_rfid/) doesn't seem to be much help, so I'm posting here as well.

I'm try to read (what I think is) an HID Duoprox II 125kHz FSK RFID and am having a bit of trouble. I'm using an Arduino nano and am copying the code from the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DIYRFIDReader). The changes I've made to the code are adjusting the frequency to 125kHz, changing debug to true, and reducing maxBuf to 100. I believe I also have to change val = digitalRead(inPin); to val = !digitalRead(inPin);, and I made grnLED turn on before "got buf num: " is sent, and turn off after. Rather than build the circuit shown, I bought an Rdm6300, reverse engineered the front end, and disconnected the back end from it, letting me use the Arduino as the back end instead.

As far as hardware goes, the reader seems to be working properly. The coil has a nice sine wave on it, and the output of the circuit seems to be a proper FSK data stream . (I scoped LedPin, 13, which is outputted by the Arduino after it has recieved the signal on pin 7.)

For some reason, the Arduino is not sending anything back to the computer. I'm fairly certain that this is somehow a software issue, despite me copying the code from the Arduino website. The TX LED does not light up at all. Even if the data being sent to the Arduino were corrupted, it should still send "got buf num: " every 100 changes of the input signal. (grnLED does turn on for 37.4ms, but no serial data is sent, and the pin never turns on again.)

What's going on? Why doesn't the Arduino send anything back to the computer?

Full code:

```c
#include "TimerOne.h"

int ledPin = 13; // LED connected to digital pin 13
int inPin = 7;   // sensing digital pin 7
int val;
int bitlenctr = 0;
int curState = 0;

#define maxBuf 100 //reduce to 100 or so for debugging
#define debug  true

char raw[maxBuf];

int index = 0;
int bufnum = 0;
#define   redLED 12
#define   grnLED 11 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.initialize(8);  // initialize timer1, and set the frequency; this drives both the LC tank as well as the pulse timing clock
  // note: modify this as needed to achieve resonance and good match with the desired tags
  // the argument value is in microseconds per RF cycle, so 8us will yield RF of 125kHz, 7us --> 143kHz, etc.

  Timer1.pwm(9, 512);           // setup pwm on pin 9, 50% duty cycle
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);  // attaches callback() as a timer overflow interrupt, once per RF cycle

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin 13 as output for scope monitoring
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);      // sets the digital pin 7 as input to sense receiver input signal
  pinMode(grnLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(grnLED, 0);
  digitalWrite(redLED, 1);
}

void callback()
{
  val = !digitalRead(inPin);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, val); // for monitoring
  bitlenctr++;
  if(val != curState) {
    // got a transition
    curState = val;
    if(val == 1) {
      // got a start of cycle (low to high transition)
      if(index < maxBuf) {
        raw[index++] = bitlenctr;
      }
      bitlenctr = 1;
    }
  }  
}

void loop()
{  
  if(index >= maxBuf) {
    digitalWrite(grnLED, 1);
    Serial.print("got buf num: ");
    Serial.println(bufnum);
    digitalWrite(grnLED, 0);

    if(debug) {
      for(int i = 0; i < maxBuf;
      i++) {
          Serial.print((int)raw[i]);
        Serial.print("/");
      }
      Serial.println("///raw data");
      delay(2000);
    }

    // analyze this buffer
    // first convert pulse durations into raw bits
    int tot1 = 0;
    int tot0 = 0;
    int tote = 0;
    int totp = 0;
    raw[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < maxBuf; i++) {
      int v = raw[i];
      if(v == 4) {
        raw[i] = 0;
        tot0++;
      } 
      else if(v == 5) {
        raw[i] = raw[i - 1];
        totp++;
      } 
      else if(v == 6 || v == 7) {
        raw[i] = 1;
        tot1++;
      } 
      else {
        raw[i] = 101; // error code
        tote++;
      }  
    }   

    // next, search for a "start tag" of 15 high bits in a row
    int samecnt = 0;
    int start = -1;
    int lastv = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxBuf; i++) {
      if(raw[i] == lastv) {
        // inside one same bit pattern, keep scanning
        samecnt++;
      } 
      else {
        // got new bit pattern
        if(samecnt >= 15 && lastv == 1) {
          // got a start tag prefix, record index and exit
          start = i;
          break;
        }
        // either group of 0s, or fewer than 15 1s, so not a valid tag, keep scanning
        samecnt = 1;
        lastv = raw[i];
      }  
    }

    // if a valid prefix tag was found, process the buffer
    if(start > 0 && start < (maxBuf - 5*90)) { //adjust to allow room for full dataset past start point
      process_buf(start);
    } 
    else {
      Serial.println("no valid data found in buffer");
    }
    if(debug) {
      for(int i = 0; i < maxBuf;
        i++) {
          Serial.print((int)raw[i]);
        Serial.print("/");
      }
      Serial.print("///\nbuffer stats: zeroes:");
      Serial.print(tot0); 
      Serial.print("/ones:"); 
      Serial.print(tot1);
      Serial.print("/prevs:"); 
      Serial.print(totp);
      Serial.print("/errs:");
      Serial.println(tote);  
      delay(1000);
    }

    // start new buffer, reset all parameters
    bufnum++;
    curState = 0;
    index = 0;
  } 
  else {
    delay(5);
  }  
}

// process an input buffer with a valid start tag
// start argument is index to first 0 bit past prefix tag of 15+ ones
void process_buf(int start) {
  // first convert multi bit codes (11111100000...) into manchester bit codes
  int lastv = 0;
  int samecnt = 0;
  char manch[91];
  char final[45];
  int manchindex = 0;

  Serial.println("got a valid prefix, processing data buffer...");
  for(int i = start + 1; i < maxBuf && manchindex < 90; i++) {
    if(raw[i] == lastv) {
      samecnt++;
    } 
    else {
      // got a new bit value, process the last group
      if(samecnt >= 3 && samecnt <= 8) {
        manch[manchindex++] = lastv;
      } 
      else if(samecnt >= 9 && samecnt <= 14) {
        // assume a double bit, so record as two separate bits
        manch[manchindex++] = lastv;
        manch[manchindex++] = lastv;
      } 
      else if(samecnt >= 15 && lastv == 0) {
        Serial.println("got end tag");
        // got an end tag, exit
        break;
      } 
      else {
        // last bit group was either too long or too short
        Serial.print("****got bad bit pattern in buffer, count: ");
        Serial.print(samecnt);
        Serial.print(", value: ");
        Serial.println(lastv);
        err_flash(3);
        return;
      }  
      samecnt = 1;
      lastv = raw[i];
    } //new bit pattern
  }

  Serial.println("converting manchester code to binary...");
  // got manchester version, convert to final bits
  for(int i = 0, findex = 0; i < 90; i += 2, findex++) {
    if(manch[i] == 1 && manch[i+1] == 0) {
      final[findex] = 1;
    } 
    else if(manch[i] == 0 && manch[i+1] == 1) {
      final[findex] = 0;
    } 
    else {
      // invalid manchester code, exit
      Serial.println("****got invalid manchester code");
      err_flash(3);
      return;
    }
  }

  // convert bits 28 thru 28+16 into a 16 bit integer
  int code = 0;
  int par = 0;
  for(int i = 28, k = 15; i < 28+16; i++, k--) {
    code |= (int)final[i] << k;
  }
  int paritybit = final[28+16];
  for(int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
    par ^= final[i];
  }

  if(par) {  
    Serial.print("got valid code: ");
    Serial.println((unsigned int)code);
    // do something here with the detected code...
    // 
    //
    digitalWrite(redLED, 0);
    digitalWrite(grnLED, 1);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(grnLED, 0);
    digitalWrite(redLED, 1);
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("****parity error for retrieved code");
    err_flash(3);
  }  
}

// flash red for duration seconds
void err_flash(int duration) {
  return;
  for(int i = 0; i < duration*10; i++) {
    digitalWrite(redLED, 0);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(redLED, 1);
    delay(50);
  } 
}
```

EDIT:

Even the following code doesn't work! All I receive is "St"! Increasing the PWM period does fix this.

```c
#include "TimerOne.h"
int val = 0;
int inPin = 7;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Starting!!");
  Timer1.initialize(8);
  Timer1.pwm(9, 512);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  }

void callback(){
  val = digitalRead(inPin);}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("hi!");}
```

Comment: If you invert what you read from pin 7, you should at least invert the initial and later settings of `curState` too as well as the `if(val == 1) ...`.

Comment: The only reason I'm inverting what I'm reading from pin 7 is because the circuit I'm using inverts the signal compared to the circuit on the Arduino website (I think.) The program should send debug information either way.

Comment: Have you tried using different serial baud rates? Just a stab in the dark...

Comment: Did you figure this out? It looks like it's printing the first 2 letters of "Starting".  Adding a delay between your print and Timer1.initialize printed the rest of it.